# Semi-definite programming, and bound on the trace distance

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, nuclear-norm

I'm quite new to semi-definite programming (SDP), and I'd like to compute a program that has some conditions on the distance between two vectors.

More precisely I have some fixed positive real $\delta > 0$ and complex semi-definite matrices $\rho \succcurlyeq 0$ and $\sigma  \succcurlyeq 0$, and I want to:

1. Minimize $t$
2. Subject to:

   1. $\rho' \succcurlyeq 0$
   2. $t > 0$
   3. $t \sigma \succcurlyeq \rho$
   4. $\|\rho'-\rho\|_* = Tr(|\rho'-\rho|) \leq \delta$ (this is the trace distance, i.e. the sum of the module of the eigen values of $\rho'-\rho$)

I can easily turn the first 3 conditions into an SDP by assuming that a matrix $X$ is positive, and enforcing the diagonal blocks of $X$ to be equal to $\rho'$, $t$ and $t\sigma - \rho'$ with linear conditions. However, I can't find how to treat the last condition $Tr(|\rho'-\rho|) \leq \delta$ as it's not linear.

Can I somehow give more conditions on $X$ to force also the last condition, or is it just that this problem can't be solved with a SDP ?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

Thanks a lot Brian Borchers for the reference! So I tried to look at the proof (page 19 for people interested), the first part goes well (the matrix it defines + computing the trace of this things just looks just a bit magic, but it works™), but for the other direction I'm not sure to see how to proceed: indeed, we suppose $\|X\|_* \leq \delta$ and we need to prove that if we define
$$\gamma = \frac{2\delta - 2 \|X\|_*}{p+q}$$
$$X = U \Sigma U^\dagger + \gamma I$$
$$Z = V \Sigma V^\dagger + \gamma I$$
then we need to prove that $Tr(Y)+Tr(Z) \leq 2\delta$ (this is easy) and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}Y & X \\ X^\dagger & Z\end{pmatrix} \geq 0$$
However this last equality is not clear to me. I was thinking to use Schur complement that seems to be quite common in SDP, which is equivalent to something like:

1. $V \Sigma V^\dagger + \gamma I \geq 0$ (easy as well)
2. $U \Sigma U^\dagger + \gamma I - X^\dagger(V \Sigma V^\dagger + \gamma I)^{-1} X \geq 0$

(remark: Schur complement seems to be true for definite matrices and not for semi definite matrices (D^{-1} does not even makes sense when $D \geq 0$), i.e. it should be $>$ instead of $\geq$... what's the equivalent for semi definite matrices?)

However, I don't see how to derive equation 2... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has now clarified that the 4th constraint is that the nuclear norm (trace-norm, etc.) of the difference between $\rho$ and $\rho^{\prime}$ is less than $\delta$.

$\| \rho - \rho^{\prime} \|_{*} \leq \delta$.

There's a standard reformulation for this, which can be found in the [SIAM Review survey paper on SDP by Vandenberghe and Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/semidef_prog.pdf).

$X=\rho - \rho^{\prime}$

$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} Y & X \\ X^{H} & Z \end{array} \right] \succeq 0$

$ \mbox{tr}(Y)+\mbox{tr}(Z) \leq 2 \delta$

Comment: A more common notation for this would be $\| \rho - \rho^{\prime}  \|_{*}  \leq \delta $.

Comment: No, that's very bad notation, since $\| \|_{1}$ means the matrix norm induced by the vector 1-norm.

Comment: Some authors use the subscript $p$ for the Schatten $p$ norm, but it's confusing because the induced matrix $p$ norm has been in widespread use for a very long time.  The nuclear norm is the most commonly used Schatten $p$ norm ($p=1$), so using $\| \|_{*}$ is a better choice of notation that avoids this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great reference and theorem! I tried to look at the proof, I agree with the first part but I'm not able to show the positivity of the matrix at the end (see my edit). Any idea how to prove that? (PS: i removed the comments for clarification above)

Comment: If by any chance you have the explanation proof (see my edit), I'm still interested !